# python json capture entire node from found element

Tags: python, json

I am loading json and trying to extract a portion. I can load the json fine and query it. Im stuck on retrieving the json node its found in.

So i have a json strcuture like the below. How would I look for an element and capture its entire node. i.e. name="7004389c-c47a-4611-9bd7-9f5dfe051d17" and then return the following:
OUTPUT Example:

```
{
            "name": "7004389c-c47a-4611-9bd7-9f5dfe051d17",
            "children": [],
            "behaviors": [
              {
                "name": "xxx",
                "options": {
                  "key": "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx",
                  "compress": true,
                  "ports": ""
                }
              }
            ],
            "criteria": [
              {
                "name": "xxxx",
                "options": {
                  "Name": "UUID",
                  "values": [
                    "7004389c-c47a-4611-9bd7-9f5dfe051d17"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ],
            "criteriaMustSatisfy": "all"
          }
```

JSON Example:

```
  "etag": "14b3796c268c87553291702c808e86dfe1e53d1b",
  "rules": {
    "name": "default",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "xxxx",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "dffaa42b-3f0f-425f-a9a1-a63cd35b2517",
            "children": [],
            "behaviors": [
              {
                "name": "xxx",
                "options": {
                  "key": "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx",
                  "compress": true,
                  "ports": ""
                }
              }
            ],
            "criteria": [
              {
                "name": "xxxx",
                "options": {
                  "Name": "UUID",
                  "values": [
                    "dffaa42b-3f0f-425f-a9a1-a63cd35b2517"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ],
            "criteriaMustSatisfy": "all"
          },
          {
            "name": "7004389c-c47a-4611-9bd7-9f5dfe051d17",
            "children": [],
            "behaviors": [
              {
                "name": "xxx",
                "options": {
                  "key": "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx",
                  "compress": true,
                  "ports": ""
                }
              }
            ],
            "criteria": [
              {
                "name": "xxxx",
                "options": {
                  "Name": "UUID",
                  "values": [
                    "7004389c-c47a-4611-9bd7-9f5dfe051d17"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ],
            "criteriaMustSatisfy": "all"
          }
        ],
        "behaviors": [],
        "criteria": [],
        "criteriaMustSatisfy": "all"
      }
    ],
    "behaviors": [
      {
        "name": "xxx",
        "options": {}
      }
    ],
    "options": {
      "is_secure": true
    },
    "variables": []
    },
  "warnings": [
  ],
  "Format": "xxx"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for a particular dictionary based on the key `name` as:

```
# assuming test contains your json data
key = '7004389c-c47a-4611-9bd7-9f5dfe051d17'
res = [node for node in test["rules"]["children"][0]['children'] if node['name'] == key][0]
```

Output:

```
{'name': '7004389c-c47a-4611-9bd7-9f5dfe051d17', 'children': [], 'behaviors': [{'name': 'xxx', 'options': {'key': 'xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx', 'compress': True, 'ports': ''}}], 'criteria': [{'name': 'xxxx', 'options': {'Name': 'UUID', 'values': ['7004389c-c47a-4611-9bd7-9f5dfe051d17']}}], 'criteriaMustSatisfy': 'all'}
```

Comment: Thanks @krishna. How would this work in the event the key is in a different part of the node. Ideally a find, and then filter like you have above would be best.